# Is it possible to make a bijection $ [0,1] \rightarrow[0, \infty)$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I found a lot of problems of bijections like $[0,1) \rightarrow[0,
\infty)$. But I don't find ant of these:

> $$\text{Is it possible to make a bijection  } [0,1] \rightarrow[0,
> \infty)? \text{ If yes, find at least one bijection.} $$

Can anyone help?

My work: I found one function: $f(x)=\frac{1}{\left( x-\frac{1}{2} \right) ^2}-4$.
What about $f(x)=\frac{1}{\left( x-1 \right) ^2}-1$?

Comment: Your function is not injective, because $f(0) = f(1)$. Do you want the bijection to be continuous?

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter if the bijection is continuous or not. But in this case the bijection cannot be continuous, right? @BrazilianCérebro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let 
$$f(x):=\begin{cases}
x&\text{if $x\in[0,1)\setminus\{1/n: n\in\mathbb{N}^+\}$}\\
\frac{1}{n+1}&\text{if $x=\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$}\\
\end{cases}$$
The function $f$ is bijection from $[0,1]\to [0,1)$ which acts as a left-shift in the set $\{1,1/2,1/3,\dots\}$ and it is the identity elsewhere. Now take your bijection $g$ from $[0,1)$ to $[0,+\infty)$ (for example $g(x)=\frac{x}{1-x}$) and consider the composition $g\circ f: [0,1]\to [0,+\infty)$.

P.S. Note that there is no continuous bijection from $[0,1]$ to $[0,
\infty)$ because $[0,1]$ is a compact set and $[0,
\infty)$ is not a compact set.

Comment: Can you give me more explanation about the function $f(x)$, @Robert Z?

Comment: @Karagum $f$ is a bijection from the set $A=\{1,1/2,1/3,\dots\}$ to $\{1/2,1/3,\dots\}=A\setminus \{1\}$. Is it clear now? Any further doubt?

Comment: @Karagum:  this is a common technique for finding bijections.  You find one that does most of what you want, then take care of the problem points.  There are many cases here of bijections between $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$ which do basically the same thing.  You can even take care of a countable infinity of points this way.  Once you know that, you stop worrying about the problem children.